# CustomVideoRecording : Video getting blurred with green lines in Samsung Galaxy3 if I am using Custom Zoom while recording

Tags: android

I am getting video blurred with green lines in Samsung Galaxy S3,
this is only if I use custom "zoom-in" otherwise it is fine.
means if I not applying any zoom it is fine, How to handle this?

This is my code for preparing camera, Zoom and recording.

```
private void prepareCamera() {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inside prepare camera ---");
    try {
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();   

        // green mess in video file without this
        mParameters.set("cam_mode", 1);


        if (mParameters.isZoomSupported()) {

            try{
                mParameters.setZoom(zoomLevel);

                //Seekbar to manage zoom
                seekBar.setMax(mParameters.getMaxZoom());

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while setting camera parameters"+e.toString());
            }

        }           

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
            mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO); // works
        }else{
            mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY); // works as well
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Orientation::::::" + this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation !=Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }else{
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        }           

        try{
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){

            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters); // catch RuntimeException
            }
        }catch(Exception ee){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while set the paramerts" + ee.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while preparing the view" + e);
    }
}
```

And for managing zoom

```
seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress = 0;
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            FFIVideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mParameters.isZoomSupported()){
                        try{
                            final int maxZoomLevel = mParameters.getMaxZoom();
                            zoomLevel = progress;
                            if(zoomLevel <= maxZoomLevel && zoomLevel > 0){
                                //mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                                mParameters.setZoom(zoomLevel);


                                mParameters.set("cam_mode", 1);
                                mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
                        }}catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            });
        }
```

And this is for Recording video

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
        AUDIO_ENCODING =  MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        VIDEO_OUTPUT_FORMAT = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
    }else{
        AUDIO_ENCODING = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB;
        VIDEO_OUTPUT_FORMAT = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP;
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "outFilePath1 path is ::" + outFilePath);
    // start media recorder
    MessageRecorderData messageRecorderData = new MessageRecorderData();
    messageRecorderData.setMediaType("video");
    messageRecorderData.setOutfilePath(outFilePath);
    messageRecorderData.setOutputFormat(VIDEO_OUTPUT_FORMAT);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    messageRecorderData.setAudioEncoder(AUDIO_ENCODING);
    messageRecorderData.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoHeight(240);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoWidth(320);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoMaxDuration(60000);
    messageRecorderData.setVideoFrameRate(15);

    mediaRecorderService = new MediaRecorderService(messageRecorderData);
    mediaRecorderService.start(mCamera, mPreview);
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.